# Зачем вообще нужна куча?

Tags: память

Я прочитал много постов посвященных организации памяти, но мне по прежнему не ясно зачем вообще нужна куча? Почему вместо нее не используется какой нибудь глобальный стек или что-то вроде того?

Comment: Куча нужна, что бы хранить динамически создаваемые объекты. Теоретически, стек можно также сделать в куче. И кучу можно сделать в стеке. Вот только зачем себе усложнять жизнь?

Comment: Тут еще неплохо бы понять что вы имеете в виду. Кучу из которой ОС выдает память при вызове `malloc()` или же конкретную структуру данных с помощью которой где-то там это реализовано. Впрочем в первом случае ответ: "для динамического выделения памяти", а во втором: "для хранения и  удобной организации данных в памяти".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Думайте о куче как о структуре, из которой можно *в любой момент* попросить кусок памяти, и в которую можно *в любой момент* эту память вернуть.

Со стеком такое не получится: в нём вы можете вернуть объект назад только после того, как все предыдущие объекты вернулись.

Например, в гипотетическом языке, в котором есть лишь стек, вот такая конструкция:

```
object* function()
{
    aux_object* ao = new aux_object();
    object* o = new object();
    o -> copySettingsFrom(ao);
    delete ao;
    return o;
}
```

была бы невозможна, потому что освободить `ao` нельзя было бы до освобождения `o`!

Comment: Да там и `copySettingsFrom(ao)` бы не вышло, на вершине, то `o`.

Answer (score 6):

Во время работы программы в оперативный памяти выделяется СТЕК (с небольшим размером) в него загружается сама программа, эта программа может работать с данными большого размера и СТЕКа ей уже недостаточно. Для таких целей эти данные размещают в КУЧЕ и там же их обрабатывают.

На пальцах можно в пример привести баню. Например вы хотите попарится в русской бане. для этого вы заходите сначала в небольшой предбанник и там раздеваетесь, а весь процесс мытья происходит в парилке, затем вы снова заходите в предбанник чтобы одеться и выйти из бани.

Comment: там вот почему именно куча?  почему не какой-то отдельный стек. Ведь насколько я понимаю расширить его не так сложно

Comment: а что вы будете делать если заранее не можете знать сколько вам потребуется памяти? стек же ограниченный по правилу последний пришел - первым ушел, а динамическая память не ограниченная и у нее произвольный доступ

Answer (score 4):

Куча - очень простая структура данных для выделения памяти под другие структуры данных. Стек совершенно не подходит, в т.ч. для хранения информации о свободных и занятых ячейках, по причине того, что доступ к данным кучи не должен быть ограничен последним добавленным элементом.

Comment: а можно пример? Как организована куча

Comment: K&R конечно. 

В общем случае, куча - это две функции `malloc` и `free`, упрощённо malloc:

`char *malloc_ptr;
void *malloc(int size)
{
  void *ret;
  ret = (void*)malloc_ptr;
  malloc_ptr += size;
  return ret;
}`

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752604/simple-c-malloc)

Comment: я не об этом. Как она физически построена, а не какие есть api для доступа к ней

Comment: [Много маленьких ячеек из конденсаторов и транзисторов.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Square_array_of_mosfet_cells_read.png)

Comment: @xalz вопрос, как устроена куча - можно свести к вопросу: "как устроен аллокатор?" или "как устроен распределитель памяти?". Что-то можно посмотреть тут: http://www.slideshare.net/viridovics/lecture-os-201305 а остальное погуглить в интернетах.

Answer (score 2):

Грубо: куча нужна для динамического выделения в ней участков памяти нужного размера.
По своей сути, и куча и стек - это участок физической памяти.